# lea ecx, [rax + 5] - что загружает?

Tags: ассемблер

где то в коде написано вот что.

```
mov     rax, [rbp+var_38]
mov     [rbp+var_18], rax
mov     eax, [rbp+var_3C]
shl     eax, 3
lea     ecx, [rax+5]
```

очень странный код для меня. похоже на какую то манипуляцию с битами. но что для меня странно, так это то, что `var_38` это указатель на выделенную память и я могу предположить, что этот адрес будет каждый раз разный при перезапуске программы. потом еще верхняя часть `rax` не меняется, а меняют `eax` и потом с помощью `lea ecx, [rax+5]` хотят получить адрес. и вот еще одна странность. это же 64 битный код. как тогда можно загружить адрес из `rax + 5` в регистр `ecx`? и что значит `rax + 5` - это типа сишного такого кода `&val[5]`?

Comment: LEA ничего не загружает, а фактически просто вычисляет значение в квадратных скобках с подставленными значениями регистров и кладет в нужный регистр (ecx в данном случае). Т.е. тут просто арифметическая операция без обращения по каким-либо адресам.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не показываете достаточно контекста, приходится гадать. Скорее всего, `var_38, var_18, var_3C` это offset, то есть коснтанта, програмно генерируемое имя локальной переменной.

```
mov     rax, [rbp+var_38]
mov     [rbp+var_18], rax
```

Это присваивание локальных переменных, типа `x = y;` Значение из `var_38` копируется в `var_18`.

```
mov     eax, [rbp+var_3C]
```

Локальная переменная копируется в eax.

`shl     eax, 3` не нуждается в комментариях.

```
lea     ecx, [rax+5]
```

Работает в соответствии с LEA, Intel Assembly Reference:

> Operand size 32, Address Size 64. 64-bit effective size is calculated, and the lower 32 bits of the address are stored in the requested 32-bit register destination.

Для чего - возможно код, следующий за этими строками, поможет разобраться. Может, это заготовка для какого-нибуть цикла, типа `rep stos`.

Comment: Скорее всего тут LEA используется просто в качестве арифметического оператора, получается выражение вида `ecx = var_3C << 3 + 5`